# Is there a way to apply a formula to only rows with matching Ids in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to apply a custom formula that involves a calculation over multiple rows to a dataset in python, but only to rows with matching IDs. Here is what my data looks like:

[image]

The formula I am trying to apply is the cumulative product of `one_plus_r - 1`, but only to rows with matching `Fund_ID`s. This loop worked perfectly, but only for the first fund ID. Everything else was `NaN`.

```py
    for i in HF['Fund_ID'].unique():
        new_data = HF[HF['Fund_ID']==i]
        new_data['cum_ror'] = np.cumprod(new_data['one_plus_ror'])-1
        HF = pd.merge(HF,new_data, how="left", on=['Fund_ID','DateTime'])
```

I am getting a KeyError and I am not exactly sure what it means. The problem appears to arise on the third line of my snippet when I reference `'one_plus_ror'`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems like maybe [groupby cumprod](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumprod.html) without a loop at all?  `HF['cum_ror'] = HF.groupby('Fund_ID')['one_plus_ror'].cumprod() - 1`?

Comment: @HenryEcker Wow I was making that way more complicated than it had to be lol. Thank you !